# Websockets will not work over TLS/SSL but will work without

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I've finally got the time to learn web sockets and have choosen to use: http://socketo.me/docs/push to do so. It all works perfectly fine without SSL. The moment it's enabled the client javascript will not connect and will output "WebSocket opening handshake timed out". I've tried the server with and without the TLS options.

client.html, post.php, server.php

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="autobahn.js"></script>
<script>


    var conn = new ab.Session('wss://domain.com:8443',
        function() {
console.log('Connected');            
conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
                // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
            });
        },
        function() {
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        },
        {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
    );

</script>
```

```php
<?php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/socket/vendor/autoload.php';

// post.php ???
    // This all was here before  ;)
    $entryData = array(
        'category' => 'kittensCategory'
      , 'title'    => 'My Impressive Title'
      , 'article'  => 'Just me the best, nothing new!'
      , 'when'     => time()
    );

    // This is our new stuff
    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
    $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

    $socket->send(json_encode($entryData));

    echo 'All Sent!';
```

```php
<?php

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/socket/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;

class Pusher implements WampServerInterface {

    /**
     * A lookup of all the topics clients have subscribed to
     */
    protected $subscribedTopics = array();

    public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
echo 'Subbed';       
 $this->subscribedTopics[$topic->getId()] = $topic;
    }

    /**
     * @param string JSON'ified string we'll receive from ZeroMQ
     */
    public function onBlogEntry($entry) {

        echo 'Hello!';

        $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

        // If the lookup topic object isn't set there is no one to publish to
        if (!array_key_exists($entryData['category'], $this->subscribedTopics)) {
            return;
        }

        $topic = $this->subscribedTopics[$entryData['category']];

        // re-send the data to all the clients subscribed to that category
        $topic->broadcast($entryData);
    }

    /* The rest of our methods were as they were, omitted from docs to save space */


    //public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
   // }
    public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    }
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }
    public function onCall(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, $topic, array $params) {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->callError($id, $topic, 'You are not allowed to make calls')->close();
    }
    public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->close();
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    }
}



    $loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $pusher = new Pusher;

    // Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
    $context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
    $pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
    $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
    $pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBlogEntry'));

    // Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
    $webSock = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8443', $loop, array(
    'tls' => array(
        'local_cert' => 'cert.pem',
    'local_pk'    => 'private.key', // path to your server private key,
        'verify_peer' => FALSE

    ))); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect

    $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
        new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
            new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                    $pusher
                )
            )
        ),
        $webSock
    );

    $loop->run();
```

Comment: Do you have certificate on your server?

Comment: Yes I do, a valid certificate issued by LetsEncrypt.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

In order for the client to work over SSL you need to set the server certificate and private key and start a secure server as follows.

```php
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', [$pusher, 'onUpdate']);

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8443', $loop);
$webSock = new React\Socket\SecureServer($webSock, $loop, [
    'local_cert'        => 'C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt', // path to your cert
    'local_pk'          => 'C:/xampp/apache/conf/ssl.key/server.key', // path to your server private key
    'allow_self_signed' => TRUE, // Allow self signed certs (should be false in production)
    'verify_peer' => FALSE
]);
//$webSock->listen(8443, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

Please see here:
https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/609#issuecomment-363743604